# Unable to change data format

Tags: sas

I need to convert dates in the following forma:

> ```
> 30-giu-18        
> 30-nov-20      
> ......
> ```

into:

> ```
> 30JUN2018        
> 30NOV2020      
> .......
> ```

I tried:

> ```
>      data Test; 
>        set input;
>        mydates = input(myolddates, ddmmyy10.;)
>        format mydates ddmmyy10.;
>      run;
> ```

It doesn't work. The variable myolddates is character $9.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What does giu represent? Why does it become jun?

Comment: It is the Italian translation of June. I need to convert the dates from Italian to eng and in the format: dummy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
data have;
input myolddates $9.;
datalines;
30-giu-18 
30-nov-20 
;

options dflang = Italian ;

data want;
   set have;
   date = input(myolddates, EURDFDE9.);
   format date ddmmyy10.;
run;
```

Comment: Judging by what he wants a format for date should be date9.